# When I add a custom R Script Tool to my ModelBuilder, it gives me this error message

Tags: r, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, sp, r-bridge

I have been trying to add an R Script Tool to my model in Model Builder within ArcGIS Pro--the tool, called Tree Detection, works well when I run it on its own, but every time I try to run it as part of the model, it gives me the following error message:

```
 Error in .handleSimpleError : error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[<-': comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types
 Failed to execute (Detect Trees).
```

I am not sure why the tool works by itself but does not work when added to the model. Below is the R script for the tool. I already tried using the arc.sp2data commands and that didn't work. I believe this issue is that for whatever reason, the model can't read the SP data type, but I am not sure how to convert it, or if there is a better method. I am somewhat new to the ArcGIS R Bridge. Also this is on ArcGIS 3.0.1.

```
tool_exec <- function(in_params, out_params) {
  arc.progress_label("Loading packages...")
  arc.progress_pos(20)
  library(ForestTools)
  library(raster)
  library(arcgisbinding)
  library(spatial)
  arc.check_product()
  arc.progress_label("Reading Data...")
  arc.progress_pos(40)
  #Tree Tops
  treetop <- out_params[[1]]
  input_raster <- in_params[[1]]
  canopy <- arc.data2sp(arc.raster(arc.open(input_raster)))
  canopyht <- raster(canopy)
  arc.progress_label("Generating Tree Tops...")
  arc.progress_pos(60)
  lin <- function(x){x * .05 + 2.5}
  minht <- in_params[[2]]
  ttops <- vwf(CHM = canopyht, minHeight = minht, minWinNeib = "rook", winFun = lin)
  arc.write(treetop, ttops)
  arc.progress_label("Generating Crown Polygons...")
  arc.progress_pos(80)
  #Crowns
  polycrowns <- out_params[[2]]
  crowns <- mcws(treetops = ttops, format = "polygons", CHM = canopyht, minHeight = 15, verbose = FALSE)
  #polysdf <- arc.sp2data(polycrowns.df)
  #ttopsdf <- arc.sp2data(ttops.df)
  arc.write(polysdf, ttopsdf)
  return(out_params)
}
```

Code adapted from educational materials from the Susquehanna River Basin Commission.

Comment: Can you narrow down the line that causes the problem? If its not immediately apparent, try inserting a `return()` statement at various points and seeing how far it gets, or adding more messages and progress statements. Once you figure out the line, then its a matter of figuring out what's wrong with the objects at that point.